# ASP ASP.NET mixed app session dies

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic

I have a site written for ASP.NET using a library written for ASP. The library resides in a dll and the site calls it to get the number of leave days an employee has left from a database. The dll was outsourced so I don't have access to the source.

I've set up the database and visual studio project locally. When I run the site and login to the system, an error message is displayed where the leave days should be displayed but the site runs normally. If I register the dll using regsvr32, the leave days are displayed when I login, but when I try to browse the rest of the site, the session is dropped and I'm automagically logged out. If I deregister the dll, then I can browse the site once I've logged in again but, once again, the error is displayed.

What could be going wrong?

Thanks
Vic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It was a silly problem. The library created a log file in the bin directory every time it did something. The session gets dropped everytime there's a change in a file in the bin directory because the site thinks it's been changed. O_o